# Modifying Parse.User object before FIRST save

Tags: parse-platform

I'm working on an app and I need some changes to be made on new users registering during certain periods.

I've added a variable which I will change manually, and a check if that value is true or false.

This is my current code:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, status)
{
  console.log("********************************************");
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var special = true;
  if(special)
  {
    request.object.set("points", 1000);
    request.object.set("role/objectid", "PZHTquGti0");
  }else{
    request.object.set("points", 0);
    request.object.set("role/objectid", "TQyjIY59oL");
  }
  console.log("********************************************");
  status.success("Job finished successfully!");
}); // end of Parse.define
```

This code errors out with "Uncaught Error: change must be passed a Parse.Object" and I've been looking through the documentation to find out how to change a value of a subclass of the User object, but have found none.

Also, this code will also run when updating a user, which I don't want it to do.
Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What is the column name & type of the role associated with the user?

Comment: The column is named role and is a pointer to a Role.

Answer (score 1):

First of all for running the code on first save (insert), you can use [request.object.isNew()](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html#isNew)

As the `role` column is a pointer, you should set an object & not the id string directly.
So create a new dummy object and assign the id to it.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, status)
{
  console.log("********************************************");
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

  if(request.object.isNew()){ // Object Insert
      var Role = Parse.Object.extend("_Role");
      var role = new Role();

      var special = true;
      if(special)
      {
        request.object.set("points", 1000);
        role.id = "PZHTquGti0";
        request.object.set("role", role);
      }else{
        request.object.set("points", 0);
        role.id = "TQyjIY59oL";
        request.object.set("role", role);
      }
  }
  else{ // Object Update
    //Do nothing
  }
  console.log("********************************************");

  status.success("Job finished successfully!");
}); // end of Parse.define
```

Comment: Hmm. still getting the same error. Is there any detailed documentation for the CloudCode feature? Never found anything about that request.object.isNew in the available docs.

Comment: `if(request.object.id == null)` also works the same way. Did you try with the new role object?

Comment: Yes. I did as you wrote. Will try with the request.object.id == null today.